# WiFI not Connecting on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I've recently booted Ubuntu into my HP Pavilion G4. However, my computer isn't trying to look for any available WiFi networks.

I checked and my Wireless LAN is neither hardblocked nor softblocked.

I tried installing the b43 driver, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I ran this script that extracts information about the wireless connections on my laptop, as suggested on the forums, and I've pasted the results of that script here, if it helps!

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7579062/

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your wireless woes!

I was experiencing issues with extremely slow wireless to no wireless.  The fix for me was to install a newer kernel.

My basic specs:

Linux Mint 17 cinnamon 64 bit

Kernel:  3.14.5-031405-lowlatency (low latency for audio mixing)

Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Mint 17 comes stock with the same kernel as Ubuntu 14.04

I downloaded the following kernels from

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.5-utopic/

linux-image-3.14.5-031405-lowlatency_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_amd64.deb
linux-headers-3.14.5-031405_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_all.deb
linux-headers-3.14.5-031405-lowlatency_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_amd64.deb

That location also has generic kernels as well, which should work just fine.

You should be able to install those with gdebi without any issues.
Let me know if that works for you.